# Difference between -static -lxyz and -l:libxyz.a

Tags: c++, linux

Sory my english is bad.
I'm using visual code, my project is c++, -L./libs/curl/lib include only libcurl.a, that is static lib
When I build project with this link option, everything is ok:

```
LDFLAGS = -static -L./libs/curl/lib -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto -lsqlite3 -lpthread -ldl -lz
```

But when I use this link option:

```
LDFLAGS = -L./libs/curl/lib -l:libcurl.a -l:libssl.a -l:libcrypto.a -l:libsqlite3.a -l:libpthread.a -l:libdl.a -l:libz.a
```

I got this error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(pthread_create.o): In function `allocate_stack':
/build/glibc-2ORdQG/glibc-2.27/nptl/allocatestack.c:526: undefined reference to `_dl_stack_flags'
/build/glibc-2ORdQG/glibc-2.27/nptl/allocatestack.c:652: undefined reference to `_dl_stack_flags'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(elision-lock.o): In function `do_set_elision_enable':
/build/glibc-2ORdQG/glibc-2.27/nptl/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86/elision-conf.c:67: undefined reference to `_dl_x86_cpu_features'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(nptl-init.o): In function `__pthread_initialize_minimal_internal':
/build/glibc-2ORdQG/glibc-2.27/nptl/nptl-init.c:294: undefined reference to `_dl_cpuclock_offset'
/build/glibc-2ORdQG/glibc-2.27/nptl/nptl-init.c:429: undefined reference to `_dl_pagesize'
/build/glibc-2ORdQG/glibc-2.27/nptl/nptl-init.c:438: undefined reference to `_dl_pagesize'
/build/glibc-2ORdQG/glibc-2.27/nptl/nptl-init.c:454: undefined reference to `_dl_init_static_tls'
/build/glibc-2ORdQG/glibc-2.27/nptl/nptl-init.c:456: undefined reference to `_dl_wait_lookup_done'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(nptl-init.o): In function `__pthread_get_minstack':
/build/glibc-2ORdQG/glibc-2.27/nptl/nptl-init.c:475: undefined reference to `_dl_pagesize'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a(dlopen.o): In function `dlopen':
(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `__dlopen'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a(dlclose.o): In function `dlclose':
(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `__dlclose'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a(dlsym.o): In function `dlsym':
(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `__dlsym'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a(dlerror.o): In function `dlerror':
(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `__dlerror'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a(dladdr.o): In function `dladdr':
(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `__dladdr'
```

So my question is:

1. What difference between -static -lxyz and -l:libxyz.a link option?
2. does -static have implicit links to add other libs?

Comment: Well, if you wish to build an executable-program that uses these libraries, you could try this: `LDLIBS = -lsqlite3 -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto -lz -ldl -lpthread`

Comment: but I want static link, that for pc don't have interner, only LAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default gcc or g++ will link against some standard libraries. The list of these libraries is architecture dependent, but you find libc libgcc and some others. To see the list of libraries used for the link you can add `-v` option. You will see the list of libraries passed to collect2. Since you are compiling for x86_64 the list will be probably (libc, libgcc and libgcc_s).

When you use the static option, you force the linker to use the static version of all the libraries, those you give with -l option and the default ones.

In the second case you give the linker the static version of your libraries, but for the other libraries it is the shared version that will be taken. `If both static and shared libraries are found, the linker gives preference to linking with the shared library unless the -static option is used.` from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options.

A last thing. The crt files are also different if you use static option. You can see it also with `-v` option.

In case you want to control exactly which library should be used there is the option `nostdlib`. when using this option, The compiler Do not use the standard system startup files or libraries when linking. No startup files and only the libraries you specify are passed to the linker, and options specifying linkage of the system libraries, such as -static-libgcc or -shared-libgcc, are ignored.

Comment: output on case 1
```
-lcurl -lssl -lcrypto -lsqlite3 -lpthread -ldl -lz -lstdc++ -lm --start-group -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc --end-group
```
Then I fix makefile like , I got output:
```
-l:libcurl.a -l:libssl.a -l:libcrypto.a -l:libsqlite3.a -l:libpthread.a -l:libdl.a -l:libz.a -l:libm.a --start-group -l:libgcc.a -l:libgcc_eh.a -l:libc.a --end-group -Bstatic -lstdc++ -Bdynamic -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc
```
It still use dynamic link
So is there a way to force g ++ to link statically without using -static.
-static force all lib static link, I don't want that.

Comment: I updated my answer, if you want to control exactly what you are using nostdlib is what you want i guess.